# jQuery seconds counter not showing in Fancybox inline

Tags: jquery, fancybox

```
var counter = 5;
var timer = setInterval(function () {
    seconds--;
    $('#regmsg').html('Successful! Message will close in ' + counter);
    if (counter == 0) {
        $.fancybox.close();
        parent.location.reload();
    }
}, 1000);
$.fancybox({
    href: '#regmsg',
    type: 'inline',
    'closeBtn': false
});
```

I want the time to show in `#regmsg` but it is only showing 'Successful!' and not the rest of the message. What is the problem? How do I fix it?

Comment: Please, next time ident your code to provide a readable code for us.

Comment: Im sorry, thnaks to Fabrício Matté, its now edited. Will do from next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `seconds` to `counter`.

```
var counter = 5;
var timer = setInterval(function () {
    counter--; // <- here
    $('#regmsg').html('Successful! Message will close in ' + counter);
    if (counter == 0) {
        $.fancybox.close();
        parent.location.reload();
    }
}, 1000);
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/Cxxx5/)

Comment: Thanks so much, next time I should make it readable for myself so I correct these silly mistakes.